# exception swallowed in RaiseAndSetIfChanged

Tags: c#, reactiveui

Normally in reactive extensions, any unhandled exceptions bubble up and usually lead to a program termination, and ReactiveUI follows this by rethrowing exceptions unless ThrownExceptions is subscribed. I was therefore surprised to see that the following code example (works in RoslynPad) doesn't actually terminate:

```
#r "nuget:ReactiveUI/9.13.1"

using System.Reactive.Linq;
using ReactiveUI;

class ReactiveExample : ReactiveObject
{
    public ReactiveExample()
    {
        var o = this.ObservableForProperty(x => x.S, skipInitial: true).Select(x => x.Value);
        o.Subscribe(s => 
        {
            Console.WriteLine("received value " + s);
            throw new Exception("throw on value " + s);
        });
        //this.ThrownExceptions.Subscribe(e => throw new Exception("uncaught", e));
    }

    public string S
    {
        get => _s; 
        set => this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(ref _s, value);
    }

    private string _s = "";
}

var r = new ReactiveExample();
r.S = "bar";
```

If you subscribe to ThrownExceptions by commenting in the corresponding line above, it is clear that indeed an exception is thrown.

Is this a bug or a feature? I believe that this is caused by the try/catch in ReactiveUI.IReactiveObjectExtensions.NotifyObservable, which I would have expected to rethrow the exception in case the ThrownExceptions observable doesn't have a subscriber instead of just logging it (see https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/blob/a4ee168dade8b5e3f34337fabd56eca10eca5200/src/ReactiveUI/ReactiveObject/IReactiveObjectExtensions.cs from line 382).

Comment: We have logging warnings that you should likely want to subscribe to thrown exceptions. Also use WhenAnyValue().Skip(1) over ObservableForProperty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://reactiveui.net/docs/handbook/default-exception-handler/

I would recommend you file a bug since the exception should propogate

Worth noting ObservableForProperty is meant for mostly internal use.

Comment: Thanks Glenn, I'll file a bug report. Also thanks for pointing out to use WhenAnyValue().Skip(1) in order to skip the initial value!

Comment: I filed https://github.com/reactiveui/ReactiveUI/issues/2013 to track this issue.